# How can I do conditional joins in python like subquery?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs.

I want to get df2's category, but there are no common keys.

df1's code should be between range1 and range2.

df2's s_date has only 2 values(20210101, 20220101)

df1

| code | date |
| --- | --- |
| A51 | 20221215 |
| C52 | 20221215 |
| A51 | 20211215 |
| D89 | 20211215 |

df2

| range1 | range2 | s_date | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A00 | B99 | 20220101 | A |
| C50 | C60 | 20220101 | B |
| A00 | B60 | 20210101 | AA |
| D00 | D90 | 20210101 | DD |

For output, I did this work using SQL like below statement,

but I want to do this work using python(pandas).

output

| code | date | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A51 | 20221215 | A |
| C52 | 20221215 | B |
| A51 | 20211215 | AA |
| D89 | 20211215 | DD |

```
SELECT 
 code, date,
 CASE WHEN date >= '20220101'
 THEN (SELECT category
      FROM df2
      WHERE code BETWEEN range1 AND range2
      AND   s_date = '20220101'
 ELSE (SELECT category
      FROM df2
      WHERE code BETWEEN range1 AND range2
      AND   s_date = '20210101') END AS category
FROM df1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that the value in `df1['code']` should be joined with df2 if it falls between `range1` and `range2`? What is the order of the ranges? Is it  `A0-A99-B0-B99-etc.`? If this this the case the ranges seem to overlap as seen in the first and third row of `df2`. There also isn't a `BB` value in `df2`, where is this coming from in the expected output?

Comment: df1['code'] is like [A-Z] + [00-99]
and to avoid overlap, there is a condition for date.
output's 4th row is error. I would edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directrly compare strings in python. For example, 'A50' > 'A00' will result in **True**, while 'A50' > 'B00' will return **False**. We can use it to filter the df2 by this values.

Here is cow it might look in code:

```
categories = []
for row in df1.values:
    code = row['code']
    date = row['date']
    if date >= '20220101':
        category = df2[(df2['range1'] < code) & (code < df2['range2']) & (df2['s_date'] == '20220101')]['category']
    else:
        category = df2[(df2['range1'] < code) & (code < df2['range2']) & (df2['s_date'] == '20210101')]['category']
    categories.append(category)
df1['category'] = categories
```

There is perhaps much more elegant approach, but the main pattern is like that.

Answer (score 0):

`date` and `code` impose an ordering on the rows. One approach is to define an integer encoding of these columns, then use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to combine the dataframes.

We'll define an encoding function which assumes `code`s are guaranteed to be three ascii characters (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801462/how-can-i-do-conditional-joins-in-python-like-subquery#comment132012336_74801462)).

```py
from struct import pack, unpack

def encode(row, code_label='code', date_label='date'):
    date_is_ge_20220101 = row[date_label] >= '20220101'
    code_as_bytes = bytes(row[code_label], encoding='ascii')
    return unpack('>I', pack('?3s', date_is_ge_20220101, code_as_bytes))[0]
```

Perform the encoding...

```py
df1['encoding'] = df1.apply(encode, axis='columns')
df2['encoding'] = df2.apply(encode, axis='columns',
                                    code_label='range1',
                                    date_label='s_date')
```

Do the merge keeping in mind that `merge_asof` requires the merge values to be sorted.

```py
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('encoding'),
              df2.sort_values('encoding'),
              on='encoding')
```

giving...

```py
    code date     encoding  range1  range2  s_date   category
0   A51  20211215 4273457   A00     B60     20210101 AA
1   D89  20211215 4470841   D00     D90     20210101 DD
2   A51  20221215 21050673  A00     B99     20220101 A
3   C52  20221215 21181746  C50     C60     20220101 B
```

For the record, I would only take this approach if absolutely necessary to meet a project's requirements. It is too far removed from the original problem statement, albeit interesting.